# Convert MD5 messageDigest from Java to Digest::MD5 Ruby

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to use Digest::MD5 on ruby like a java code.
This is the java code:

```
public static String MD5Encode(String input, String salt) {
        try {
            MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            byte[] hash = null;

            try {
                messageDigest.update(salt.getBytes("UTF-8"));
                messageDigest.update(input.getBytes("UTF-8"));
                hash = messageDigest.digest();
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException exception) {
                logger.error("MD5Encoder:Encode:" + exception.toString());
            }

            if (hash != null) {
                StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder(2 * hash.length);

                for (byte b : hash) {
                    output.append(String.format("%02x", b & 0xff));
                }

                return output.toString();
            }
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException exception) {
            logger.error("MD5Encoder:Encode:" + exception.toString());
        }

        return null;
    }
```

and this is the ruby code, but the result is not right:
(the input variable in java is the password variable on ruby, and the salt variable is the same on both)

```
 salt = SecureRandom.hex
  if (params[:gamestate_password] != "")
    password = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(params[:gamestate_password] + salt)
    user_query = "UPDATE user_v54 SET password= '#{password}', passwordSalt= '#{salt}' WHERE userId='#{params[:userId]}'"
  end
```

Comment: You put salt in front of password in java and the other way round in ruby.

Answer (score 0):

You should put the salt in ruby the same order as in java (in front of password):

```
password = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(salt + params[:gamestate_password])
```